# Ripped DVD Video Playback Stutters, original DVD does not

Tags: conversion, transcoding, playback

I have a DVD of home video made from a VHS that I'm trying to rip so I can post it to YouTube. I've ripped a couple of videos using both Mac DVDRipper Pro and Handbrake to compare the output after I noticed some stuttering in my first rip. The videos from both apps have stutters in the same spots but the stuttering doesn't exist when I play the disc in DVD Player.

It's not often, sometimes every couple of minutes for just a moment. Other times it will go 5 to 8 minutes without any stutter. I've noticed momentary sound dropping out for these stutters in both QuickTime and in QuickLook, and also just now in VLC. It's nothing major but annoying and something I'd like to fix seeing as the source DVD doesn't have these playback issues.

Could extracting the DVD as a disc image first and ripping that solve the stuttering playback?

I'm ripping from the optical drive in my 27" iMac under Mavericks. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it on different machines or different playback software - quicktime, vlc etc.? It could just be a playback issue on the machine you're using.

Comment: I haven't tried it on a different machine but I did try in QuickTime and VLC with the same result. However, I just ripped the DVD again with DVDRemaster 7.0.1 and am not finding any more glitches. Seems to be an issue with Mac DVD Ripper Pro and Handbrake.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the framerate of the rip doesn't match the framerate of the DVD. I would check if those match. The QuickTime Inspector can do this or a great tool called [MediaInfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo).

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't have thought to check that. Using MediaInfo I've checked the frame rates from the DVD and the exported M4V files generated from Mac DVDRipper Pro and Handbrake. I've posted the results here:

http://s29.postimg.org/qra65vnxj/mediainfo_footage_compare.png

The DVD sources are the same and frame rates for the rips match their 29.970 fps. Yet resolutions, bit rates and audio seem to vary not only from rip to rip but from within the same app. Even though the source is exactly the same. I'm very confused.

Comment: The ripping procress in your case is not lossless. You are not simply copying the dvd content your are transcoding it into a whole new format. That results in different bitrates, even in the same app.

Answer (score 1):

Something you could try is to copy the VOB files from the DVD and concatenate them all into one MPEG file, then you can see if the original file is corrupted.

Here's how:

- open your DVD in Finder, and navigate to the VIDEO_TS folder. Inside will be all the DVD files .BUP, IFS and VOB. The VOB files are the video objects, they're what you want.
- Now find which VOB files are your actual content. Look at the file sizes, it will be the larger ones. For each title on the DVD there is a set of **VTS_** **x_y**.**VOB** files where **x** is the title number, like 01, 02, 03, and **y** is the part number. Each title will be composed of one or more VOB files, so for VTS_01 there will be

> VTS_01_0.VOB
>
> VTS_01_1.VOB
>
> VTS_01_2.VOB

and so on. You want to join these together (excluding the one numbered zero).

- You can use the cat command to copy them to a new file and join them together. Open the Terminal and type `cat` (make sure you type a space after cat). Then drag the VOB files for each title onto the terminal window, starting at number one - so excluding number 0. It will fill in the path for you. it should look like this:

  `cat /Volumes/DVD_name/VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB /Volumes/DVD_name/VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_2.VOB /Volumes/DVD_name/VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_3.VOB`
- now we want to send them all to a new file, using the redirection operator `>`. Type <kbd>></kbd> (the greater than symbol) after the list of VOB files and then type the name of the file you want to create, with a `.mpg` suffix, eg `newvideofile.mpg`. By default terminal opens in your home folder, if you want it to write the file somewhere else you have to type in the path. For example to write it to your desktop use `~/Desktop/my_new_video_file.mpg` **Don't use spaces** in the file name, or if you do make sure you put quotes around it.

  `cat /Volumes/DVD_name/VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB /Volumes/DVD_name/VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_2.VOB /Volumes/DVD_name/VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_3.VOB > mynewvideofile.mpg`

This will take a while, depending on how large your video files are and how fast your DVD drive is. Once it's done you'll have an mpg file which you can view or transcode.

Comment: Thanks so much. I completely forgot about your reply and decided to go back and try your suggestion. I followed your instructions and while Terminal did out put a MPG it was only about 20 seconds long. The file size was 1.49 GB, however, which seems odd for such a short segment. I left Terminal for an hour but saw no further change in file size. I couldn't tell it was still working but I was able to quit the app when I saw no 'cat' process in Activity Monitor. Thanks again but I'll have to try something else or just live with the little glitches.

Comment: I just ripped the DVD again with DVDRemaster 7.0.1 and am not finding any more glitches! Seems to be an issue with Mac DVD Ripper Pro (4.1.9) and Handbrake (0.10.1). I even changed Handbrake's settings to match DVDRemaster's as closely as I could but a new rip generated the same glitches. I'm not sure what the problem is but I'm glad I tried DVDRemaster!